# Duplicate columns in CSV file

Tags: perl, csv, hash

I have a CSV file that I wish to turn into an array of hashrefs in Perl.  This is a solved problem.  The complication is that this file contains duplicate column names, and I'd like to map the duplicate column names such that if there are two columns named 'Field1', for example,  the returned hash has keys 'Field1_1' and 'Field1_2', but if there is only one column named 'Field3', the corresponding key in the returned hash is 'Field3'.

So for a file:

```
'Field1','Field2','Field3','Field1','Field4'
'alpha','beta','gamma','delta','kappa'
```

The generated hash should be:

`$hash = {
    'Field1_1' => 'alpha',
    'Field2' => 'beta',
    'Field3' => 'gamma',
    'Field1_2' => 'delta',
    'Field4' => 'kappa',
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crux of your question boils down to how to append increasing numeric suffixes to duplicates in an array. You can add the suffix to all duplicates but the first in a single pass like this:

```
my %seen;
my @header = qw(Field1 Field2 Field3 Field1 Field4);
my @fields = map { $seen{$_}++ > 0 ? $_ . '_' . $seen{$_} : $_ } @header;
```

The first occurrence of `Field1` will be unchanged, while the second occurrence becomes `Field1_2`. To append the suffix to *all* duplicates, including the first, would require multiple passes. Here's one approach:

```
my %seen;
my @header = qw(Field1 Field2 Field3 Field1 Field4);
$seen{$_}++ for @header;

# Filter out non-dupes
for (keys %seen) {
    delete $seen{$_} if $seen{$_} <= 1;
}

my @fields;
for (reverse @header) {
    if (exists $seen{$_}) {
        unshift @fields, $_ . '_' . $seen{$_}--;
    }
    else {
        unshift @fields, $_;
    }
}

__END__
Field1_1, Field2, Field3, Field1_2, Field4
```

With [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm), you can specify the column names using the `column_names()` method (surprise, surprise). The following reads a CSV into an array of hashrefs using the mapped column names from the simpler single-pass approach:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ binary => 1, auto_diag => 1})
        or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

open my $fh, '<', 'file.csv' or die $!;

my $header = $csv->getline($fh);

my %seen;
my @fields = map { $seen{$_}++ > 0 ? $_ . '_' . $seen{$_} : $_ } @$header;

$csv->column_names(\@fields);

my $rows = $csv->getline_hr_all($fh);

print Dumper $rows;

close $fh;
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = [ 
          { 
            'Field4' => 'kappa',
            'Field2' => 'beta',
            'Field1_2' => 'delta',
            'Field1' => 'alpha',
            'Field3' => 'gamma'
          }
        ];
```

Answer (score 1):

ThisSuitIsBlackNot's answer was certainly thorough and helpful.

That said, I would like, for the sake of the fact that Perl can be bent like a yoga teacher in a hot sauna, to show that if the suffix wants to be appended to all duplicates this *can* be done in one line but know, it is way ugly:

```
my @foo = ('123','234','345','123','456', '000', '234', '123');
@foo = map {my $idx = $_; my $val = $foo[$idx]; grep($foo[$_] eq $val, 0..$#foo) > 1 ? $foo[$_]."_".scalar(grep($foo[$_] eq $val, 0..$idx)) : $foo[$_]} 0..$#foo;
print Dumper(\@foo) . "\n";
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
      '123_1',
      '234_1',
      '345',
      '123_2',
      '456',
      '000',
      '234_2',
      '123_3'
    ];
```